# Need query for following scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a result like followed by

```
ID Name Status
1   A     Y
2   A     N
3   B     Y
4   B     Y
5   C     N
```

in this case if status of Name A have two status then I need a select query for following outout

```
ID Name Status
1   A     N
2   A     N
3   B     Y
4   B     Y
5   C     N
```

And sorry, I dont know how ask question for this scenario..

please provide the solution thanks in advance

Comment: You want the N row only, if it exists, otherwise one the Y rows?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your attempt(s) please?

Comment: How come you want changed ID values?

Comment: the question is unclear. provide more details.

Comment: @jarth --- i want change staus of Name A if status N occurs even one time

Answer (score 1):

This following script will select data as per your requirement-

```
SELECT yt.ID, 
yt.Name, 
CASE WHEN A.N>1 THEN 'N' ELSE Status END as Status
FROM your_table yt
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Status) as N
    FROM your_table 
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Status) >1
) A on yt.Name = A.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

In below query the `derived table a`  pulls the distinct record that has `'N'` . Then joined it with main table and using case statement pulled the `status`.

> Using `Derived Table`

```
 select *,
    case when a.name is not null then 'N' else #temp.status end [status]
    from #temp
    Left join (select distinct name from #temp where status ='N' )a on a.name = #temp.name
```

> Using `Case Statement`

```
select *, 
         case (select count(*) from #temp t where status='N' and t.Name = #temp.Name)
          when 1 then 'N'
          else status 
          end   [status]
from #temp
```

**OR**

```
select *, 
         case when (select count(*) from #temp t where status='N' and t.Name = #temp.Name)  > 0 then 'N'
          else status 
          end   [status]
from #temp
```

**Output**

```
ID  Name    Status  name    status
1   A         Y     A       N
2   A         N     A       N
3   B         Y     NULL    Y
4   B         Y     NULL    Y
5   C         N     C       N
```

Comment: I am using multiple joins already, the above one difficult to apply

Comment: try handling it in case statement.  I have added code for case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE` in the SELECT will work in this case.

Demo with sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (ID INT, [Name] VARCHAR (1), [Status] VARCHAR (1));

INSERT INTO @TestTable(ID, [Name], [Status]) VALUES
(1, 'A', 'Y'),
(2, 'A', 'N'),
(3, 'B', 'Y'),
(4, 'B', 'Y'),
(5, 'C', 'N');

SELECT T.ID, 
       COALESCE(Q.[Name], T.[Name]) AS [Name], 
       COALESCE(Q.[Status], T.[Status]) AS [Status]
FROM @TestTable T
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Name], 'N' AS [Status]
    FROM @TestTable
    WHERE [Status] = 'N'
) AS Q ON Q.[Name] = T.[Name]
```

Output:

```
ID  Name    Status
1   A       N
2   A       N
3   B       Y
4   B       Y
5   C       N
```

Comment: I am using multiple joins already, the above one difficult to apply

Comment: Then store those multiple joins result into a temp table, then apply the query above

Answer (score 0):

Use a RANK in separate query to get the status for the latest id and left join on name against that query to use latest status for all rows for a name

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.status
FROM dbo.Table_3 a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, name, status, RANK() OVER (Partition BY name ORDER BY id desc) AS rnk
           FROM dbo.table_3) b ON a.name = b.name AND b.rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Windowed function so that you don't need to scan the table twice:

```
SELECT ID,
       [Name],
       CASE COUNT(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'N' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name]) WHEN 0 THEN [Status] ELSE 'N' END AS [Status]
FROM (VALUES(1,'A','Y'),
            (2,'A','N'),
            (3,'B','Y'),
            (4,'B','Y'),
            (5,'C','N')) V(ID, [Name], [Status]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example, you can just use a window function:

```
select ID, Name,
       min(Status) over (partition by name) as status
from t;
```

This works because `'N'` is less than `'Y'`, so the `MIN()` will return `'N'` if any values are `'N'`.